# How do I rewrite this SCSS Mixin that uses a @for loop

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

I need help with a  scss mixin. I am trying to add an animation delay using nth:child() selectors by utilizing a for loop inside a mixin. The delay on each child should increase in increments of .5 seconds.

```
li {
    list-style: none;
    transform: translateX(100rem);
    animation: slideIn .5s forwards;

    &:nth-child(1) {
      animation-delay: 0s;
    }

    &:nth-child(2) {
      animation-delay: .5s;
    }

    &:nth-child(3) {
      animation-delay: 1s;
    }

    &:nth-child(4) {
      animation-delay: 1.5s;
    }
}
```

I have replaced the original scss with a mixin. Please note the first child above has an animation delay of 0s.

```
@mixin delay {
    @for $i from 1 through 4 {
        &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
            animation-delay: $i * (0.5s);
        }
    }
}
```

The final code.

```
li {
    list-style: none;
    transform: translateX(100rem);
    animation: slideIn .5s forwards;
    @include delay;
}
```

This works fine except it adds a delay to the first child. How do I rewrite this mixin so it will skip the first child and begin on the second child?

Comment: `@for $i from 2 through 4`

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't perform as expected. It just adds a longer delay to the second child.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop from 2 to 4 (as @mfluehr said is his comment 'cause by default `animation-delay` is 0 => https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-delay.asp), adding `($i - 1)` to your `animation-delay`.

So, this could be your new mixin:

```
@mixin delay {
    @for $i from 2 through 4 {
        &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
            animation-delay: ($i - 1) * (0.5s);
        }
    }
}

li {
    list-style: none;
    transform: translateX(100rem);
    animation: slideIn .5s forwards;
    @include delay;
}
```

Your output:

```
li {
  list-style: none;
  transform: translateX(100rem);
  animation: slideIn 0.5s forwards;
}
li:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
li:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
li:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}
```

I add also an example with new CSS without `li:nth-child(1)`:

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  transform: translateX(100rem);
  animation: slideIn .5s forwards;
}
li:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
li:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
li:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes slideIn {
    100% { transform: translateX(0); }
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>1</li>
 <li>2</li>
 <li>3</li>
 <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This worked! What I didn't include when I tried looping 2 through 4 was ($i - 1). Would you be willing to help me understand that line of code? I guess I don't get why you would need to add that portion when you specify 2 through 4.

Comment: Sure. Because you want that the second li starts with a delay of 0.5s no 1s (2*0,5 = 1). To do this, we have to remove a unit of $i at each loop (2-1=1 then 1*0.5=0.5; 3-1=2 then 2*0,5=1; 4-1=3 then 3*0,5 = 1,5...)

Comment: That makes sense. It will just take some practice to wrap my head around it.